# How to manually invoke a dispatch in struts with spring beans properly initialized

Tags: java, spring, struts-1

I'm developing an app to automate a set of long operations from the back end, that currently has to be done by the user.

So I'm required to invoke the relevant dispatch methods in the Actions, from the Action of the program I'm developing.

The Action I'm developing is

```
public class AutomatedAction extends DispatchAction{

    public ActionForward create(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        MyAction myAction = new MyAction();
        myAction.myDispatch();

        // Want to call more dispatches like this

        return null;
    }
}
```

And a sample of MyAction class is

```
public class MyAction extends DispatchAction{

    public ActionForward myDispatch(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        // Some code
        getSomeBD().doOperation();
    }
}
```

but the problem I'm facing is inside myDispatch() method, there are Spring beans used for layer mapping, like -

```
getSomeBD().doOperation();
```

Which works fine with the manual way, but I'm getting a NullPointerException with the above code when I'm inspecting the getter of the bean -

```
getSomeBD()
```

Can anyone explain why this happens? As I know, spring beans are initialized when the server starts up, so why throw me a NullPointer?

Comment: You're creating `MyAction` yourself by calling `new` -> spring beans won't be injected in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aleksandr M has mentioned, I found the answer. Because spring beans won't be injected by calling `new MyAction()`, I'd have to get the MyAction bean itself from the Context.

So what I did was add - `implements ApplicationContextAware` to the `AutomatedAction` class.

```
public class AutomatedAction extends DispatchAction implements ApplicationContextAware{}
```

By implementing `ApplicationContextAware` we can override its

`public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context);`

method and get the application context to an instance variable by defining one. Then I was able to fetch the bean from the context, instead of creating a new instance.

```
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
    public void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

So the final coding looks like this.

AutomatedAction class -

```
public class AutomatedAction extends DispatchAction implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
    public void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ActionForward create(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        MyAction myAction = (MyAction) getContext().getBean("/MyActionBean");
        myAction.myDispatch();
        // do more
        return null;
    }
}
```

MyAction class (no changes)

```
public class MyAction extends DispatchAction{

    public ActionForward myDispatch(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        // Some code
        getSomeBD().doOperation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good that you have solved this out. It is better though to move your `getSomeBD().doOperation();` to some service and inject that service instead of using another action.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks @Aleksandr M